# Get current cordova version

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova app with Visual Studio 2017. I need to display the Cordova version that my project is currently using inside my app. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal in Mac or the command prompt in Windows and run the following command

```
cordova -v
```

It will give you the version number and whether you need to update it to the latest version or not. 
If you want to know the cordova version from your index.js file then use this -

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.cordova);
}
```

Find the full documentation here - [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html)

Comment: @Barlo577 can you mark this as the correct answer, please?